# jquery sortable modify helper

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

i have some problems with jquery sortable:

This is my code:

```
$('.sortable-list').sortable({
        helper: function (e, ui) { return $(ui.get(0)).clone().appendTo('body').css('zIndex', 5).show();},
        connectWith: '.sortable-list',
        placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
}).disableSelection();
```

i like to add a sourrounding div to the helper. But `return '<div>'+$(ui.get(0)).clone().appendTo('body').css('zIndex', 5).show()+'</div>';` wont work.

Can somebody help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to check this option : http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-containment

EDIT :

Have you tried JQuery wrap ?

See here : http://api.jquery.com/wrap/
You would do something like :

```
$('.sortable-list').wrap('<div class="new" />');
```

Comment: thanks the containment option binds a drag element to a container. i only like to add a sourrunding div to the helper to add a class to the div and style it.